# Open-Source library for Database management in Java

Tags: java, database, open-source

Is there any open-source library in Java for getting deep information about database, its tables, schema and ... (size in bytes, records, etc.)? I need to connect to database (various distributions) and get as much as possible meta and statistics about each!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered JDBC ;-)

It contains all the data you would likely need in the *MetaData structures, in your case: [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) ?

Comment: Definitely yes but unfortunately is not enough for my project. I need something more abstract for faster developing. I need something like MS SQL Management Studio, or MySQL workbench but Java based and Open-Source.

Comment: As soon as you need more detail than JDBC gives, then tou can't (easily) do different dbms .